# Saving opencv.Filestorage in custom destination

Tags: python, opencv

can't understand how to write cv2 FileStorage object to a new directory that is not the current working one.

this added code saves to CWD

for tile in tiles:

```
    fs_write = cv2.FileStorage('{}.xml'.format(tile.number), 
    cv2.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)
    fs_write.write("mat_pointcloud", tile.image)
    fs_write.release()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'{}.xml'.format(tile.number)` is a string with formatting, you have several options:
either prepend your path

```
'path/to/{}.xml'.format(tile.number)
```

or if you have different paths do:

```
'{}/{}.xml'.format(path_to_dir, tile.number)
```

in general read up on [new style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)